# Extension for Chrome that redirects you to an existing tab if you try and open the same url

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, google-chrome-extensions, plugins

I guess I'm looking for a "unique tab" extension that would behave as follows:

1. I open a new tab and type in "mail.google.com"
2. It looks for an already open tab with that url
3. If found, it takes me to that tab and closes the current one.

It should also work the same if I follow a link, like to google calendar - to find the existing calendar tab, rather than a new one.

Basically, I find it easier and faster to open a new tab rather than find an existing one. Which means I have like 4 calendar tabs open. Which means every alarm goes off 4 times...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT** Previously linked extension doesn't work. [Only One](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ffkdlcmdgpagmbokblekleghfkjgpjdo?hl=en), however appears to work flawlessly.

> This should do the trick for you,
>   though the logic is a bit differet in
>   that it closes the OLD tab and opens
>   the NEW tab. Same effect in the end
>   though.

Comment: Perfect! (It does behave the way I described - closes the new tab, redirects to the old one). You have to tell it each site that should be unique.

Comment: this is far from perfect. you have to electively say for each tab that you want it to be a singleton - and plus if you have multiple windows open it isn't able to jump to another window. it just closes the tab as you type the url. it this not technically possible? someone needs to solve this problem

Answer (score 5):

[Fast Unique Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fast-unique-tab/dpgkjbmiapibpdjnnoalnlkcmeepocak?hl=en) is what you're looking for.

The other extensions mentioned here are vastly outdated and some simply don't work.

Answer (score 4):

Based on review [here](http://www.gtricks.com/chrome/prevent-duplicate-tabs-of-same-url/) -

1. [Duplicate Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/duplicate-tab-helper/oaceoebbkmkgfjhmngdinoclnionlgoh?hl=en-GB) - Simple, effective and fast
2. [Clutter Free](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clutter-free-prevent-dupl/iipjdmnoigaobkamfhnojmglcdbnfaaf) - Same with Whitelisting option. #recommended
3. Unique Tabs - Only notification, no redirection

Answer (score 1):

I have found [Unique Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unique-tabs/cicbejncjmbkbahiicbiflndmhbcgibk?hl=en), which works without telling each single instance that you want it to be unique.