# Chrome jumps to an existing tab when I type a URL

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

When I type a url (say, superuser.com), Chrome jumps to reuse an existing tab already open at that tab. I once found this useful (indeed, I [asked a question](https://superuser.com/questions/240236/extension-for-chrome-that-redirects-you-to-an-existing-tab-if-you-try-and-open-t) requesting it!) I'd now like to get rid of it. Frequently I actually do want two tabs open to the same site - so currently the only workaround is to use "duplicate tab".

Now, I'm not using any extensions that could explain it (certainly not Only One). Is there some other option somewhere that could cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you have Chrome's "Focus existing tab on open" experimental feature enabled:

[image]

If that's the case, open chrome://flags/, find "Focus existing tab on open" feature and disable it. Relaunch browser for the effect to take place.

Comment: Bingo. I knew there had to be some hidden options somewhere.

Comment: This option has been removed however the behavior recently started occurring for me.

Comment: @George looks like the recent UI changes in chrome also changed that behaviour

Answer (score 0):

For new chrome versions:

> Omnibox switch to tab suggestion

is available in chrome flags.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1128466)