# Jump to tab using keyboard in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, tabs

I am looking for something similar to the chrome extension, [DeadMouse](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/deadmouse/kioijmpindokaaahaeigkkkbogccljhm) for jumping tabs. I know there is Ctrl+#, but is there a way to use some sort of hotkey to then switch tabs via typing in text? I have searched and cannot find an extension that already does this. [Focus existing tab on open](https://superuser.com/questions/443271/chrome-jumps-to-an-existing-tab-when-i-type-a-url) does not appear to be available anymore...at least not in my updated chrome. Will I have to create my own extension?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an extension to do just that (though 5 years too late for the OP). [QuicKey (available in the Chrome webstore)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quickey-%E2%80%93-the-quick-tab-s/ldlghkoiihaelfnggonhjnfiabmaficg) adds a drop-down menu of recently used tabs that you can navigate via the keyboard. But you can also search for a tab by its title or URL, and then switch to it.

There are other tab extensions that let you search for a tab, but most don't do a great job of ordering the results. QuicKey uses a variation of the [Quicksilver](https://qsapp.com/) algorithm to sort the results, so you can type a query that matches capital letters or the beginnings of words, like *nyt* for *The New York Times*, but that doesn't appear as a substring. Recently used tabs also get boosted in the results, so usually it takes just a few characters to find the tab you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pin these tabs (right click -> Pin Tab) and use Ctrl-# you mentioned?

Or Ctrl-Shift to go to the next tab (and Ctrl-Shift-Tab) to switch between two adjacent tabs?

Comment: First, I have too many pinned tabs. Second, it is much more convenient to type cnbc than remember it is the 7th tab.