# Open a new tab in Chrome or switch to an existing one with the same URL (cmd)

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, cmd.exe, url, tabs

I've been looking through chrome.exe's parameters and switches but couldn't find anything usable for this purpose:

Open a new tab from CLI or focus on an existing one if the URL matches

Example: `chrome.exe "https://www.google.com"`
This command opens a new tab of chrome with the URL `https://www.google.com`, regardless of an existing tab with the same URL.

Is there any way to switch/focus to an existing tab of chrome if it has the same URL from cmd?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extension for Chrome that redirects you to an existing tab if you try and open the same url](https://superuser.com/questions/240236/extension-for-chrome-that-redirects-you-to-an-existing-tab-if-you-try-and-open-t)

Comment: @JosefZ it does work, I honestly think it is a horrible solution but it does get the result done, so thank you!